# Notification symbol that looks like a droplet in a circle - what is it?

Tags: notification-icons

Is anyone able to identify this notification symbol for me?

[image: Notification symbol that looks like a droplet in a circle]

Comment: What device and Android version? That might help narrow things down a bit if it's a system icon.

Comment: It's a new Galaxy 4 which ships with 4.2.2.

Comment: Would be better if you can describe it more: is it persistent (cannot be removed)? is it showing randomly for a moment (might be GPS)?

Comment: A friend asked me to research this for them so I don't know all the details... but she said the next day it was gone so it is definitely intermittent.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a GPS or location service as they tend to have [similar features](https://encrypted.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=voice%20search%20icon&tbs=imgo:1#newwindow=1&tbs=imgo:1&tbm=isch&q=gps%20icon&imgdii=_).